# Visual Studio 2015 Update 3 - getting setup blocked error during installation

Tags: visual-studio-2015, installation, blocked

I am trying to install Visual Studio 2015 Update 3 and am getting a setup blocked error. I don't have any previous version of Visual Studio installed in my machine either. What is a remedy for this?

[image]

Below are the last few lines from the log file.

```
[1654:26C4][2017-06-28T11:40:44]i000: MUX:  Detect Completed
[1654:26C4][2017-06-28T11:40:44]i000: MUX:  Wait for View to be loaded
[1654:26C4][2017-06-28T11:40:44]i000: MUX:  View loaded
[1654:26C4][2017-06-28T11:40:44]i000: MUX:  Checking for update...
[1654:26C4][2017-06-28T11:40:44]i000: MUX:  Setup update feature is enabled. Evaluating conditions to determine whether to run setup update.
[1654:26C4][2017-06-28T11:40:44]i000: MUX:  Checking http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=659005 for update.
[1654:26C4][2017-06-28T11:40:46]e000: MUX:  Exception: Info: Could not download update data.
[1654:26C4][2017-06-28T11:40:46]e000: MUX:  WARNING: For security reasons DTD is prohibited in this XML document. To enable DTD processing set the ProhibitDtd property on XmlReaderSettings to false and pass the settings into XmlReader.Create method.
[1654:26C4][2017-06-28T11:40:46]e000: MUX:  Stack:    at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Throw(Exception e)
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ThrowWithoutLineInfo(String res, String arg)
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseDoctypeDecl()
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseDocumentContent()
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Read()
   at System.Xml.XmlLoader.Load(XmlDocument doc, XmlReader reader, Boolean preserveWhitespace)
   at System.Xml.XmlDocument.Load(XmlReader reader)
   at Microsoft.Devdiv.Bootstrapper.DownloadManager.DownloadXml(String url, Int32& returnCode)
[1654:26C4][2017-06-28T11:40:46]i000: MUX:  Failed to download the update xml file from http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=659005 Setup will not be updated.
[1654:26C4][2017-06-28T11:40:46]i052: Condition 'NOT (CurrentOperation = "Uninstall")' evaluates to true.
[1654:26C4][2017-06-28T11:40:46]i052: Condition 'NOT (CurrentOperation = "Uninstall")' evaluates to true.
[1654:26C4][2017-06-28T11:40:46]i052: Condition 'NOT (CurrentOperation = "Uninstall")' evaluates to true.
[1654:26C4][2017-06-28T11:40:46]i052: Condition 'NOT (CurrentOperation = "Uninstall")' evaluates to true.
[1654:26C4][2017-06-28T11:40:46]i052: Condition 'NOT (CurrentOperation = "Uninstall")' evaluates to true.
[1654:26C4][2017-06-28T11:40:46]i052: Condition 'NOT (CurrentOperation = "Uninstall")' evaluates to true.
[1654:26C4][2017-06-28T11:40:46]i052: Condition '(CurrentOperation = "Install") OR (CurrentOperation = "Repair")' evaluates to true.
[1654:26C4][2017-06-28T11:40:46]i000: MUX:  Configuring feed...
[1654:26C4][2017-06-28T11:40:46]i000: MUX:  Stop Block: NoApplicableUpdates : Update 3 requires a member of the Visual Studio 2015 family to be present or is blocked by another condition on your computer.
[1654:26C4][2017-06-28T11:40:46]i000: MUX:  Online feed url authoring not found
[1654:26C4][2017-06-28T11:40:46]i000: MUX:  Stop Block: NoApplicableUpdates : Update 3 requires a member of the Visual Studio 2015 family to be present or is blocked by another condition on your computer.
[1654:26C4][2017-06-28T11:40:46]i000: MUX:  Go to Blocker page.
[1654:26C4][2017-06-28T11:40:46]i199: Detect complete, result: 0x0

  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0t7KS.png
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer to the error message in the Visual Studio installation screen. You directly install the Visual Studio 2015 update 3 which is only an update for Visual Studio, and it applies to the computer that already installed any Visual Studio 2015 versions.

You need to download the **Visual Studio 2015 community/enterprise/profession with update 3** to install, please access [Download older versions of Visual Studio](https://www.visualstudio.com/vs/older-downloads/) and click ‘**Join now for free >**’ if you do not have a subscription account. Sign in with your Microsoft account and join the Visual Studio Dev Essentials, then click the ‘**Downloads’** menu and search with the keyword, then you will get the result like the following, click the Visual Studio 2015 version that you require and find the download link to download. It should work.

[image]

Comment: I tried installing visual studio professional 2015 with update 3 and this is installing fine!Thanks! :)